# Getting the value of a form field after keypress event

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events

`myInput.value` is one keystroke behind when I examine it in a `keyPress` event handler. So if the users types "a", `myInput.value` gives me "". Then when the user types "b", `myInput.value` gives me "a", and so on. The value doesn't seem to get updated with the character input by the keystroke that triggered the event. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use the keyUp event, it should definitely give you the value you are looking for.

Comment: Yep. The new keypress is applied to the value *after* calling onkeypress — as long as you don't cancel that event by returning false from your handler. Keyup, on the other hand, happens after the keypress has finished.

Comment: If I could use `keyUp` I would use it, but too bad it's not cancelable

Answer (score 4):

When I had this problem, the thing I actually wanted was the [`oninput`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_oninput.asp) event handler.

One notable difference between this and the keyUp solution is that if you e.g. hold down a key to repeat it, oninput will get called every time the key repeats, but keyUp will only get called when the key is released.